# Loop through database to post to Facebook Page

Tags: php, facebook

I am super new to this so I apologize if this has a simple solution.

I've got a file running every 12 hours to search the database for new entries. If there is a new entry, it gets posted to the Facebook page. It works, but it only posts one entry even if two or more are in the query.

It might just be that I have the if statement in the wrong place, but I'm just stuck trying to figure it out.

I'd be grateful for any advice or link to tutorial.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
        $linkData = [
            'link' => $url,
            'message' => 'Thank you for the positive review!' . "\r\n\r\n" . '"' . $row["review"],
        ];

        try {
             $response = $fb->post('/me/feed', $linkData, $pageAccessToken);
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
             echo 'Graph returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
             exit;
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
             echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
             exit;
        }
        $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it might be more likely that Facebook is suppressing these posts ... especially considering that you are making multiple posts in a short time interval (almost simultaneously), and that they all start with the same message.

Comment: Thanks CBroe, that might be the case. 

I've decided, for now, to have everything post automatically after the form is submitted instead of relying on a cron job. If I decide to revisit the cron job route and figure out the issue I will update it here.